# What does this "take" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have difficulty getting the meaning of "take" in this sentence.

> So what will it **take** to reform a decades-old mode of transport that is entrenched not only in the daily lives of millions, but in the national psyche?

Does "what will it take to reform...?" mean something like:

> what will be like if a decades-old mode of transport is reformed...?

or

> what will be necessary to reform...?

or something else?

Comment: "What will it take" means "What is required". I can't find any supporting evidence, since *take* is used in so many ways. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

"Take to" is not a consituent here.

The verb is "take", in the sense of "cost", or "require".

The construction is "What would it take [in order] to reform ... ".

So it's your second suggestion: what will be necessary to reform.

[There is a phrasal verb "take to", meaning "get to like", but it is not relevant here].